# Spark 3.2 with Scala 2.12 version

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Some time ago, the Spark site had a Spark version 3.2 that cames with the scala 2.12 version.  This is a version I am trying to find.  If it is in one of the sites below, I cannot find it there.

Specifically looking for Spark 3.2 with a Scala 2.12 version.

```
Is it still available?
```

- https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
- https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/

Link to a more thorough archive of spark (specifically 3.2.4 but others reside in the folder above this link)

- https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.2.4/

Comment: Spark 3.2 is by default built for Scala 2.12.  There are also builds available against 2.13, but unless a download is specifically identified as being against 2.13, Spark 3.x builds are against 2.12.

Comment: I've installed Spark without the (Scala 2.13) on a RHEL 8.8 Linux operating system running on a virtual box.  When running "scala -version" the indicator is the version is 2.10.6 but the command for spark-submit shows the Scala version as 2.12.15

Answer (score 3):

As it is detailed in the [downloads](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

> Note that **Spark 3** is **pre-built** with **Scala 2.12** in general and Spark 3.2+ provides additional pre-built distribution with Scala 2.13.

Also when you click to select which version you want to download, you can see that there are two options for **Spark 3.2**. One says that comes with **scala 2.13** and the other one doesn't clarify anything because it's the default.

[image]

You can find any released published in [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark). If that is not enough, you can [build spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) with the setting you need

Comment: Wow, - so good to hear. That makes the solution much easier than I would have initially though. Thanks for a great explanation, Gaston. The confusion comes with the download that indicates Scala 2.13. It would help if Spark put the words "Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.2 and later (Scala 2.12)", as the Scala portion is what to look for if you are running Databricks somewhere on line.